# Negative number of rows inserted

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, insert

I just ran a rather simple INSERT statement (that I think processed a lot of rows), and I got the message:

> -1,311,750,183 rows inserted

Should I be concerned about the fact that it's negative?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I smell 32-bit DB software.

Comment: SQL Developer.  How can I check if I'm using 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: SELECT * FROM V$VERSION

Comment: Nope, it's 64 bit:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
"CORE 11.2.0.2.0 Production"
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible that the [number of rows exceed the value of PLS_INTEGER](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm). Here is the quote from Oracle on `%ROWCOUNT`.

> `%ROWCOUNT` Attribute: How Many Rows Were Fetched? `%ROWCOUNT` returns:
>       Zero after the explicit cursor is opened but before the first fetch
>       Otherwise, the number of rows fetched (a `PLS_INTEGER`)
>       Note:
>       If the number of rows exceeds the maximum value for a `PLS_INTEGER`, then `SQL%ROWCOUNT` returns a negative value. For information about
>   `PLS_INTEGER`, see "[PLS_INTEGER and BINARY_INTEGER Data Types](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/datatypes.htm#i10726)".